# How should GCP Datastore index should be created with inequality query and multiple sort fields?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to write a query where I can sort by 2 columns see below

[GCP Query Window Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TOme.png)

Query only sorts on `created_datetime` not on both `created_datetime` and `price`

Below are the indexes I have created

```yaml
- kind: indicator_values
  properties:
  - name: currency
  - name: created_datetime
    direction: desc
  - name: price
  

- kind: indicator_values
  properties:
  - name: currency
  - name: created_datetime
    direction: desc
  - name: price
    direction: desc
```

I am not able to figure out what kind of index I have to create. Can I get some help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that share code as images instead of code blocks usually indicate you haven't read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and people often skip right over them. So share your code as indicated. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually create the indexes. Run your application in a dev (local) environment using datastore emulator and your indexes will automatically be created for you. You can then upload the index when you deploy your App to production.

See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator)

> In addition, the emulator can help you generate indexes for your production Datastore instance and delete unneeded indexes.

Comment: The indexes I have mentioned above are auto generated by running application in dev environment integrated with datastore.

Comment: okay. If your indexes are being auto-generated, why then are you asking about creating indexes?

Comment: Because auto-generated indexes are not working. I have tried many other combinations still didn't work. I wanted to get help to create right indexes or identify the issue I am doing wrong.